# I don't understand Angular NgModules

Tags: angular, ng-modules

I went into few videos explaining NgModules and the official Angular documentation about NgModules but I'm still having a grasp about how it works.

I understand that components goes into `declarations`, modules into `imports` and services into `providers` (**I also heard that since Angular v6, services don't need to be declare at all?**).
What I don't understand is when and why to create "sub NgModules" like `auth.module.ts`.

- Why should I create those sub NgModules?
- What is the benefit vs using only `app.modules.ts`?
- Should I import those sub NgModules into `app.modules.ts`?
- Is there any other things I need to know about NgModules?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why should I create those sub NgModules?

Angular follows a [modular structure](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodules#angular-modularity) to enhance code structuring, readability and re-usability.
Quoting the docs:

> NgModules consolidate components, directives, and pipes into cohesive blocks of functionality, each focused on a feature area, application business domain, workflow, or common collection of utilities.

Additionally, sub-modules allow you to implement [lazy loading](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules).

> What is the benefit vs using only app.modules.ts?

Angular recommends a Modular structure for reasons mentioned above. Additionally, check out the [style guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#application-structure-and-ngmodules).

> Should I import those sub NgModules into app.modules.ts?

It depends. If you use routing, you can lazy-load these modules and as such don't have to import them into the root module. Angular will do that itself, once a URL associated with this module is hit. You will have to [configure](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#configure-the-routes) this behavior, of course.

> Is there any other things I need to know about NgModules?

There is a LOT of useful documentation on ngModules over at the [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodules). In fact, most, if not all of your questions can be answered by reading them in depth.

NgModule FAQs: https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I strongly recommend you that go through the Angular official [site](https://angular.io/) for the better understanding.
I can explain you in one word.

***1) Why should I create those sub NgModules?***

You can implement **[Lazy-loading](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules).**

***2)What is the benefit vs using only app.modules.ts?***

You can register each thing you create in Angular, and group them together.

***3)Should I import those sub NgModules into app.modules.ts?***

Yes, You have to do that. But, if you are implementing lazy-loading it is not necessary to do so.

**4)Is there any other things I need to know about NgModules?**

Yes, Refer [this](https://medium.com/@cyrilletuzi/understanding-angular-modules-ngmodule-and-their-scopes-81e4ed6f7407) link or go through the Angular official [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodules).

Comment: It's not really necessary to import sub modules into app.module if you're implementing lazy-loading..

Comment: @AamirKhan Yes, If we are implementing lazy-loading.

Comment: Well, you've mentioned in point 3 that you **have** to import sub modules into the root module. I'm just pointing out that it's misleading, since it's not always the case.

Comment: @AamirKhan Yes, you are right. I updated the answer.